# nopcommerce issue with reinitializing

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, nopcommerce

`sdf` file that was associated with my install. I also cleaned my build and rebuilt the solution.

However when I try to restart the `nop.web` solution, I face this error:

> An exception of type 'System.Exception' occurred in
>   Nop.Web.Framework.dll but was not handled in user code.
>
> Additional information: No store could be loaded

This exception occurs in `WebStoreContext` inside the `Nop.Web.Framewo`rk where it is looking for a cached store which it cannot find so it throws an error.

My question is how can I go back to the initial state and go through the installation process again. I'm using visual studio 2013 ultimate.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could try exiting from IIS Express in the systray?